# Set base path for routing

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net, iis

I have an ASP.NET app running on a local IIS server. The app is for internal use only, so it's just a subdirectory on the server. In debug, I always just used a leading slash for routing to make it based off the root directory, `localhost` in this situation, so it just worked perfectly fine with everything. Now, the root directory is the base server, which is just the IIS splashscreen.

Is there any way that I can set a different root across the ASP.NET (for redirecting in backend), HTML (for href), javascript (for frontend redirecting), and CSS (for fonts and stuff)? Ideally this could be done dynamically so that it wouldn't have to be changed before deploy.

I found the `<base>` tag for the HTML side, but it doesn't seem to work very well with internal servers with a direct link to the network location.

#### Example

HTML

```
<!-- Current -->
<a href="/foo"></a>
<!-- Navigates to //serverhost/foo -->

<!-- Wanted -->
<a href="/foo"></a>
<!-- Navigates to //serverhost/myapp/foo -->
```

C#

```
return Redirect("/")
// Goes to "//serverhost"

return Redirect("/")
// Should go to "//serverhost/myapp"
```